# Direct web URL to PayPal transaction

Tags: paypal

Having implemented PayPal's Website Payments Standard, I'd like to link to the details view of a transaction from my site's back end - just a simple direct web URL to the PayPal side.

I don't know why this is tricky but when I try to get it from being logged in to the PayPal system it seems very obfuscated, in this form:

> history.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_history-details&info=[looks like some kind of GUID]&ptype=4&history_cache=[huge encoded string]

I'm guessing it's by design but it's not very helpful if you want a quick way to jump to a transaction's details. I've tried the `https://www.paypal.com/vst/id=1234` form (also with co.uk as I am UK-based) recommended on a few sites I saw in my search, but I am told that:

> The transaction ID in your link is invalid.

This happens even when copying the transaction ID directly from PayPal's back-end order listing.

Is there a reliable way to directly link to an order / transaction details page in PayPal?

Answer (score 22):

I found a link that seems to work:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=XXXXXX
```

For sandbox:

```
https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=XXXXXX
```

In the link, replace XXXXXX with the transaction ID.

Got this from an email confirmation of payment. Of course, no way to know how long that will work for, it's not exactly a documented feature. PayPal could change it at any point. But it should work at least today.

Comment: Can I do something similar with the URL when I send a "buy now" link to a customer? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020144/how-to-dynamically-create-a-paypal-url

Answer (score 1):

The latest URL is https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_view-a-trans&id=xxxxxx.

This is form an email in march 2014

Comment: That would probably be just for UK accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are asking is possible with Website Payments Standard. However, should you decide it prudent to upgrade your account you can make use of additional API calls, namely [GetTransactionDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails).

An alternative would be to utilize PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) system, to have it inform your application of the transaction after it is processed. You could then store this data locally, and pull it from your database programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm already storing some details about the transaction but I don't want to replicate lots of information in my database when all I should need is the items ordered and a reference to tie it back to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `info` parameter in the PayPal URL you provided is created using some sort of encryption that tells PayPal which transaction the user is currently viewing. In order to create a link from your backend directly to the transaction on PayPal's website, you would have to figure out how they are creating that parameter -- and this is most likely going to be pretty hard to do.

The bottom line is that there is no easy way to do what you are trying to do. Even if you were to replicate the way that PayPal encrypts the `info` parameter, PayPal could change that encryption or the URL to view transactions at any point and then you would be out of luck again.

As @Louis suggested, you could pursue an alternative method of displaying the transaction details (i.e. upgrade your PayPal account and seek use of an API call to get the details of a transaction or use IPN).

Comment: I'm baffled that this isn't a more common request considering PayPal have decided to go the obfuscation route for basic links.

Oh well, the workaround is that the shop administrator is going to use the Gmail account as the "hub" so they'll have access to the site-side and PayPal-side emails from the same place, which is nifty enough for the purpose.